# What is the SendMessage Equivalent in wxWidgets

Tags: wxwidgets

I want to send synchronous event from a worker thread to the UI Main thread. How do I do it in wxWidgets? A link to a sample would be really helpful

Answer (score 7):

You should use **QueueEvent(wxEvent* event)** for interthread communication.

`void wxEvtHandler::QueueEvent(wxEvent* event)`

wxDocumentation states:

**QueueEvent()** can be used for inter-thread communication from the worker threads to the main thread, it is safe in the sense that it uses locking internally and avoids the problem mentioned in **AddPendingEvent()** documentation by ensuring that the event object is not used by the calling thread any more. Care should still be taken to avoid that some fields of this object are used by it, notably any **wxString** members of the event object must not be shallow copies of another **wxString** object as this would result in them still using the same string buffer behind the scenes.

You can do it this way:

```
wxCommandEvent* evt = new wxCommandEvent();

// NOT evt->SetString(str) as this would be a shallow copy
evt->SetString(str.c_str()); // make a deep copy

wxTheApp->QueueEvent( evt );
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: as an addendum: This function is public in wxEvtHandler but protected in wxWindow because for wxWindows you should always call ProcessEvent() on the pointer returned by `GetEventHandler()` and not on the wxWindow object itself.

Answer (score 1):

**AddPendingEvent** - This function posts an event to be processed later.
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxevthandler.html#wxevthandleraddpendingevent

**ProcessEvent** - Processes an event, searching event tables and calling zero or more suitable event handler function(s).
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxevthandler.html#wxevthandlerprocessevent

```
wxFrame * frame = new wxFrame(...);
...
wxCommandEvent event(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, ID_MY_BUTTON);
frame->AddPendingEvent(event);
```

Regarding how to use this from worker thread - You'd rather take a look at Job Queue
http://wxforum.shadonet.com/download.php?id=673

Answer (score 0):

**ProcessEvent** - synchronous event handling.
It's declared as **SendMessage** equivalent.
But as I tested it does NOT switch to widget's thread, it processes in current thread!

**AddPendingEvent** and **QueueEvent** - variations of **PostMessage** (asynchronous event handling).